# Golang Gorm: Same query constructed differently throwing different results

Tags: mysql, sql, go, go-gorm

I want to run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM artists
WHERE name LIKE '%roll%';
```

the `WHERE` clause will be dynamic, meaning that I'll iterate through a map to build it and chain it to the main query.

Having said that, before even trying the iterate I thought about testing the method chaining (I'm new with Gorm) so I ran:

```
var artist entities.Artist

query := as.db.Model(&artist)

query.Where("name LIKE ?", "%roll%")
if err := query.Find(&as.Artists).Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
```

as you can see I'm chaining different parts of the query and finalizing it with `Find`. This is returning all elements in the table. After printing out the executed query I'm getting:

```
SELECT * FROM `artists`  WHERE `artists`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

no mention of the `LIKE` clause, furthermore, I don't know where the `deleted_at IS NULL` is coming from. Although at the moment it doesn't matter since ultimately I was gonna add that to the query as well.

But if I run:

```
var artist entities.Artist

query := as.db.Model(&artist)

if err := query.Where("name LIKE ?", "%roll%").Find(&as.Artists).Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
```

I'm getting the results I'm expecting. The executed query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `artists`  WHERE `artists`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND ((name LIKE '%roll%'))
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know where the `deleted_at IS NULL` is coming from

You may be extending your model with [`gorm.Model`](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#gorm-Model) which include `DeleteAt` field which is cause of `deleted_at IS NULL` being added to the query. `DeleteAt` is used to check if the record is deleted then not include it in result

> no mention of the LIKE clause

```golang
var artist entities.Artist

query := as.db.Model(&artist)

query.Where("name LIKE ?", "%roll%") <- will return new query
if err := query.Find(&as.Artists).Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
```

As Bill pointed `Where` returns new query with modified conditions however since you are not assigning it anything it will not be added to query

```golang
var artist entities.Artist

query := as.db.Model(&artist)

if err := query.Where("name LIKE ?", "%roll%").Find(&as.Artists).Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Here you are using `Find` over the newly returned query which includes the condition hence it works as expected.

To chain multiple where condition in queries you can achieve in various ways:

1:

```
var artist entities.Artist

query := as.db.Model(&artist)

query = query.Where("name LIKE ?", "%roll%")

if err := query.Find(&as.Artists).Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
```

2:

```
var artist entities.Artist

query := as.db.Model(&artist)

err := query.
          Where("name LIKE ?", "%roll%").
          Where("name LIKE ?", "%m%").
          Find(&as.Artists).
          Error
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the examples of using `query.Where()` in the documentation (https://gorm.io/docs/query.html) show chaining, like in your second example.

I conclude that `Where()` does not modify the SQL of the instance `query`, it returns a new query instance with the condition included.

Comment: as per an answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358756/how-to-execute-nested-query-in-golang-gorm it seems like you can build up the query using `WHERE` statements

Comment: But in that answer, they use `query = query.Where(...)` so they are replacing the old value of query with the new query returned by Where(). Think of code like `i = i + 1`. That replaces the value of variable `i` with the result of the expression. If you were to just do `i + 1` as a statement, it wouldn't change `i`.